# How to change my code from div tag to textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<h1>JavaScript File API demo</h1>
<div id="container">
<label>Upload files to local repository:</label><input type="file" accept=".js" id="uploaded" multiple="multiple"/>
<div id="fileInfo" ></div>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="fileInfo2"></textarea> 

</div>

<p></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(!(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)){
    $('#fileContent, input, button, #examples').fadeOut("fast");
    $('<p>Oh no, you need a browser that supports File API. How about <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google/a>?</p>').appendTo('#container');
  } else {
          $("#uploaded").change(function (e) {
                var files = e.target.files; // FileList object
                // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
                var output = [];
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                  output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), 
                            '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                            f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                            '</li>');
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function(e) {
                      $("#fileInfo").append("<li> Data from file: "+"<br/>" + e.target.result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>\&nbsp") + "</li>");
                  };
                  reader.readAsText(f);
                }
                $("#fileInfo").append('<ul>' + output.join('') + n/a +'</ul>' );
          });
  }
});
</script>
```

this code, shows the data from one or more selected files in a div tag, with the id="fileInfo", used in the last line of code...and the 3rd from below

is there a way to make my code work with the textarea, with the id="fileInfo2" ? i also changed the last line to be like this:

```
$("#fileInfo2").append("<li> Data from file: "+"<br/>" + e.target.result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>") + "</li>");
$("#fileInfo2").append('<ul>' + output.join('') + n/a +'</ul>' );
```

but id didnt work...

can u help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to place html insite textarea is to store the existing textarea value and set a new instead of using `append`. So replace:

```
$("#fileInfo2").append("<li> Data from file: "+"<br/>" + e.target.result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>") + "</li>");
```

with

```
var existingValue = $("#fileInfo2").val();
$("#fileInfo2").val(existingValue+"<li> Data from file: "+"<br/>" + e.target.result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>\&nbsp") + "</li>");
```

and

```
$("#fileInfo2").append('<ul>' + output.join('') + n/a +'</ul>' );
```

with

```
var existingValue = $("#fileInfo2").val();
$("#fileInfo2").val(existingValue+'<ul>' + output.join('') + n/a +'</ul>' );
```

Comment: op op....it does....it was my foult on a differend part of the code!! thx man u saved me...